# How to extract digits in an array

Tags: arrays, string, labview

I have this array.

[image]

I would like to remove units like uF, V and change the array into like this.

[image]

Could anyone please explain how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is a simple solution which you can use to get first number of your strings in LabVIEW. What I am doing here is taking the given array in for loop, search for first number with match regular expression and then outputting these numbers in second array.
[image: Labview example]

Comment: Note that this will work just for integers. For floating point numbers it will not find match for decimal places.